# IOS SDK / duplicate symbol for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, architecture, sdk, duplicates

I can´t find any solution on my problem. I have a duplicate error on my app. But as soon as i delete the Reachabilty.m i have another error, as i need this file in another ViewController

```
duplicate symbol _kReachabilityChangedNotification in:
/Users/Sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackQuiz-fyuyditzrtsdmgbefbdoggekhfeg/Build/Intermediates/TrackQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/TrackQuiz.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Reachability.o
/Users/Sven/Documents/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS7/AdMobMeditation/Leadbolt/libAppTracker.a(_ATReachability.o) 
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Try: add Reachability again. Clean. And search `kReachabilityChangedNotification` in your project

Comment: You have two classes that are using same symbol, not just Reachability.
Find the other class you will find the problem.

Comment: Okay, i found the extern NSString *kReachabilityChangedNotification is it okay just to change it like this extern NSString *kReachabilityChangedNo on every place?

Answer (score 2):

You had copy files two multiple time in your project.

complete remove Reachability Class From YOur Project. then Add again it. then Check ,it might be working fine.